# Yahoo! Travel API

Tags: yahoo-api

Is anyone using the Yahoo! Travel API?  I'm trying to look through their documentation, however everything is leading to dead links ("Trip Search" and "Get Trip" links).

http://developer.yahoo.com/travel/

For those that are using it, do you happen to have examples or know where I could find documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yahoo! recently added a message to their site:

> The Yahoo! Travel Trip Planner web
>   service is no longer supported.